# Memory leak in using a list of lists

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, stdlist

I had some code thrown at me to 'productionize.' I ran a memory leak checker and it calls out the following line within the 'for' loop below as a memory leak.

```
someStruct->arrayMap = new std::list<BasisIndex>*[someStruct->mapSizeX];
for(int i=0; i<someStruct->mapSizeX; i++){  
    someStruct->arrayMap[i] = new std::list<BasisIndex>[someStruct->mapSizeY];
}
```

Here is how the array map is declared:

```
struct SomeStruct{
    int mapSizeX;
    int mapSizeY;
    std::list<BasisIndex>** arrayMap;
};
```

Here are a couple usages of it:

```
someStruct->arrayMap[xVal][yVal].push_back(tempIndex);

for(it = someStruct->arrayMap[xVal][yVal].begin(); it != someStruct->arrayMap[xVal][yVal].end(); it++){
    ...
}
```

The memory leak checker dumped for 5 minutes before I killed it.  Then I added the following bit of code in a cleanup routine but it still dumps out 150 warnings all pointing to the line of code within the for loop at the top.

```
for(int x=0; x<someStruct->mapSizeX; x++){
    for(int y=0; y<someStruct->mapSizeY; y++){
        someStruct->arrayMap[x][y].clear();
        someStruct->arrayMap[x][y].~list();
    }
}

std::list<BasisIndex> ** temp = someStruct->arrayMap;
delete temp;
```

How do I completely delete the memory associated with this array map?

Comment: Use a `std::vector<std::vector<std::list<T> > >` instead. Allocating STL containers with `new` is ***horrible***. (And by horrible I mean killing puppies horrible)

Comment: @Billy: Actually it's much worse. It's killing kittens!

Comment: I don't have much experience with usage of these containers.  Why is this such a bad practice?  This code needs to be as fast as possible, but memory usage isn't as much of a concern.  Thanks

Comment: Because there's no reason to dynamically allocate them. Make them automatic variables instead. This has nothing to do with the containers specifcally, but generally how one uses objects in C++, period. If you're messing with pointers all the time in modern C++ there's a problem. That's what `scoped_ptr`, `unique_ptr`, `shared_ptr`, `auto_ptr` and friends are for. (Of course if you're interfacing with some C API that's always going to be different ;) )

Comment: While you're at it you would probably be happier with `std::vector` instead of `std::list`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deallocate the objects in the reverse order that you allocated them.

Allocation:

```
someStruct->arrayMap = new std::list<BasisIndex>*[someStruct->mapSizeX];
for(int i=0; i<someStruct->mapSizeX; i++){  
    someStruct->arrayMap[i] = new std::list<BasisIndex>[someStruct->mapSizeY];
}
```

Deallocation:

```
for (int i=0; i<someStruct->mapSizeX; i++){
    delete[] someStruct->arrayMap[i];
}
delete[] someStruct->arrayMap;
```

Comment: Sure it does. How are you going to `delete[] someStruct->arrayMap[i]` if you `delete[] someStruct->arrayMap` first?

Comment: Yes, that's true -- that does matter. However, you can nuke the `someStruct->arrayMap[i]`s in any order. It need not be the reverse order in which they were allocated.

Comment: I knew we had misunderstood each other. =)

Answer (score 3):

`someStruct->arrayMap[x][y].~list();` <-- You should not call the destructor manually. (I didn't even know it was valid to do it that way when placement new wasn't used first...) You need to use `delete` instead.